FORMA CORRETA DE UTILIZAR A FUNÇÃO LISTAGG
O script abaixo é para trazer a quantidade de cargas que demorou mais de 20 minutos para ser concluída, porém preciso trazer apenas em 1 linha todos os códigos de funcionários que trabalharam nesse carregamento e também preciso saber quanto tempo cada carregamento demorou para ser finalizado mas ao utilizar a função listagg é necessário incluir no GROUP BY o campo TAB2.TEMPO trazendo incorreto os resultados. Como utilizar a função LISTAGG nesse cenário e traga o tempo correto?
SELECT TAB2.NUMCAR, TAB2.CODFILIAL, LISTAGG (TAB2.CODFUNCOS,';')WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TAB2.CODFUNCOS ASC) CODFUNCOS, ROUND(TAB2.TEMPO,2) TEMPO FROM Relacionar o item (SELECT DISTINCT (TAB.NUMCAR), TAB.CODFILIAL, TAB.CODFUNCOS, TAB.TEMPO FROM (SELECT DISTINCT (M.CODFUNCOS) CODFUNCOS, M.CODFILIAL, M.NUMCAR, MIN(M.DATAGERACAO) DATAGERACAO, MIN(M.DTPRIIMP) DATAPRIIMP, MIN(M.DTINICIOOS) DATAINICIOSEPOS, MIN(M.DTFIMSEPARACAO) DTFIMSEPOS, MAX(M.DTFIMSEPARACAO) DATAFIMSEPOS, MIN(M.DTINICIOCONFERENCIA) DATAINICIOCONFOS, MAX(M.DTFIMCONFERENCIA) DATAFIMCONFOS, MAX(M.DTFIMOS) DATAFIMOS, (SELECT MAX(S.DTMOVLOG) FROM PCMOV S WHERE S.NUMCAR=M.NUMCAR) DATASAIDA, ((SELECT MAX(S.DTMOVLOG) FROM PCMOV S WHERE S.NUMCAR=M.NUMCAR) - MIN(M.DTFIMCONFERENCIA))2460 TEMPO FROM PCMOVENDPEND M WHERE M.DTESTORNO IS NULL AND M.DATA>=TRUNC(SYSDATE-10) AND M.CODFILIAL='1' AND M.CODROTINA=1752 AND M.POSICAO ='C' AND M.DTINICIOCONFERENCIA IS NOT NULL AND M.CODOPER='S' GROUP BY M.CODFILIAL, M.NUMCAR ,M.CODFUNCOS ) TAB WHERE TAB.TEMPO>0)TAB2 WHERE TAB2.TEMPO>=20 GROUP BY TAB2.CODFILIAL, TAB2.NUMCAR , TAB2.TEMPO


Não repita perguntas, restaure a pergunta original e siga as orientações fornecidas, se precisa comentar também faça na pergunta original.
